# How to use XEP 198 (Stream Management) from smack 4.1?

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, smack, stream-management

I am new to XMPP. I'm using smack on android for providing chat in my application.

In smack 4.1, support for stream management is added so I used

```
  XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementDefault(true);
```

to enable this and I'm getting :

```
03-27 00:50:54.945: D/SMACK(16991): SENT (5): <enable xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' resume='true'/>
03-27 00:50:55.740: D/SMACK(16991): RECV (5): <enabled xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' id='g2gCbQAAAAVTbWFja2gDYgAABZNiAAYRuGIAAW06' resume='true' max='300'/>
```

So, XEP 198 is working fine both on my client and the server(ejabberd 15).

But my question is -> do I have to write my own code for storing the messages(which are not acknowledged by the server) into my android sqlite database  and manually resend them using `chat.sendMessage();` when the connection is reconnected? OR is this resending part is done by Smack itself?

I didnt get any documentation for using XEP 198 on smack 4.1 other than  `XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementDefault(true);`

Is there any method available from smack for listening to the `<a/>` received from the server?

I have seen source code of [yaxim](https://github.com/pfleidi/yaxim), but it seems they have written their own code(by sending packets) for supporting XEP 198 which is now done in Smack 4.1.

Please help me with what should I do after enabling this support?

Comment: I know that the documentation about Stream Management is missing. But since Smack is open source you could try if looking at the source answers a few questions.

Answer (score 6):

1. Of course you need to store your pending messages and resend them when connection is back.
2. We have one way to listen message ack. Check out this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/37289804/4085494

Comment: when i'm offline that time ejabbered forward message via FCM are repeat when i'm coming online in ejabbered channel so , what i have to do in my case?